# Combining Animations for Colllada export

Tags: blender, collada

I need to export an animated character to the Collada file format in Blender. My .blend file has the individual animations (idle, walk cycle, attack, etc) each as separate actions. I discovered after creating it that the Blender Collada exporter cannot export multiple actions, so I need to merge them into one action which can be exported. I have tried the NLA editor, but the resulting NLA track which I create isn't exported at all. Is there any way to convert the track back to an action? Is there another, better way to achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can use "Bake animation" to get an action back out of the NLA editor.